# Insert query taking time to load the data into a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, sqlperformance

I am trying to insert into a table, having one primary key, using a select query. The select query pulls the data from different tables based on some business criteria. But, when we are trying to load the data using this select query, the insert process is taking more than 20min. However, there are no issues with the select query, the select query fetches the data in 2sec and data being loaded into target table is truncate and load.

This is what am trying basically:

```
insert into TAB_A 
from 
    (select 
     col1,
     col2,
     substr(col3,1,4),
     substr(col4,1,-1) 
     from A 
     inner join B 
         on A.x = B.x
    )
```

Appreciate your valuable inputs to remove this bottleneck.

Dex.

Comment: Can you recreate the scenario (on sqlfiddle or somewhere else) with your actual or similar schema and share it here? Because it's hard to help without schema or actual data.

Comment: A few thoughts (the best I can do with the little info provided). First, are you sure the SELECT query **completes** in less than 2 seconds? Some front-end programs may begin to display rows long before the entire query has finished, and it may seem as if it only takes 2 seconds when in fact it takes much longer. Can you see how many rows the SELECT query generates?

Comment: Then: is something else locking the table in which you are trying to INSERT? Can you instead just take a few rows from the output and INSERT them quickly? (For example, in your SELECT query add a condition like `where rownum <= 10` - that should insert only the first 10 rows.) Then don't forget to `ROLLBACK`!

Comment: @mathguy 50k is the count and even the select count query completed in less than a sec.

Comment: OK, that is good information - so then the suspicion has to turn to the insertion process - you may safely assume there is no issue with the SELECT part. You can try the small experiment I suggested above - are you able to insert ten rows quickly, or does that hit the same wall?

Comment: @mathguy 10 records are inserted instantly ...10k records took 1min, 50k records took 5min when executed from toad....when the insert statement is run through StoredProcedure it took 20min...only thing addition in sp is the logging statements

Comment: OK. 1 minute for 10k records still seems too much. Is this over a db link, or is it in the same database as the source tables? Then: your tests show that the problem is not the SELECT statement, or inserting into the target (although as I said, 1 minute for 10k records, 5 minutes for 50k records is still on the high side). So, then, what does the stored procedure look like? That's the next logical candidate. You will need to show the code and see if we can find anything out of the ordinary in it.

Comment: 1min for 10k and 5min for 50k is what I tried directly in toad without stored procedure just insert with select stmnt. Both source and target tables are in the same database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154275/discussion-between-dex-and-mathguy).

Comment: Can you try: create table tab_c select ....(same select)?. There could be some heavy processing while inserting into the target table (like triggers, constraints, etc). You can check the waits, is it on read/write/direct write, etc.Check also if you're using parallel processing, ..